# How to Close Tab/Window

Tags: panel, workspaces

I've looked everywhere but I can't find the solution.
How can I remove the 'this window' tab from my environment?
I want to close it.

UPDATE:
Needed to be using a mouse instead of trackpad to see the pop up menu.
[image: pan]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit : Make sure you are using a mouse with right-click capability.

Right click on the tab and choose *Delete*

[image]

If the popup doesn't appear then there is something wrong with your installation or this is a bug.

You might try resetting Blender to factory settings or there is a hidden feature I do not know in the preferences to disable it...

To reset to factory settings (**Caution** this will revert every setting you changed after the installation)

[image]

Comment: No menu is popping up.

Comment: I have edited my answered, does this help ?

Comment: See my edit. Thanks for your help! I upvoted you.

Comment: Oh, right didn't think about that ! Cheers